# Change previous element on hover

Tags: html, css

I have got list like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to change first element style when hovering the second one, using only css and html?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible with only CSS.

Comment: let me know if someway its help you. http://jsbin.com/mekaguxi/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hacky but gets the job done. A different approach.

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li:hover:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #F00;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
li:first-child:hover:before {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/4wycoksm/1/

Answer (score 4):

I am removing the styles of next siblings on hover, so that it looks like only previous siblings have styles added on hover.

```css
ul:hover li {
  color: blue;
}
ul:hover li:hover ~ li{
  color: red;
}

ul li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the previous element with only css and html is impossible, but if you are willing to use JQuery, you can use this:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('someClass');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/3LaGg/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the next but not the previous. To change the next:

```
<style>

ul li:hover+li {
/* CSS */
}

</style>
```

Comment: Read OP question carefully he already mentioned that want to select previous element.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Read mehuls answer, He can't.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you certainly can not achieve the desire output, you have to use jquery.

I've tried to make it using CSS with `:target` selector to achieve this buts its required to add some extra element like `a` with `href` attribute.

Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mekaguxi/1/edit)**.

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
    <li id="first">first</li>
    <li id="second"><a href="#first">second</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#second">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code**

```
:target
{
background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

Comment: Nice sollution, but he still has to click. Not hover :/

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson, Well where CSS ends at which point `jquery` magic start from there. :)